# How to print normal RDLC report despite machine resolution

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, rdlc, report-viewer2012

I am developing a Windows Form application in c# .Net 4.5.1 and I 've added few rdlc reports as part of it. Each report was added for a different purpose and is being shown in a separate form based on user request. Each form is simple it simply calls the adapter to populate a dataset then refreshes the report to display it:

```
namespace TestReporting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CMSDataSet.BillingDoc' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.BillingDocTableAdapter.Fill(this.CMSDataSet.BillingDoc);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I **print** the report or when I press **print layout**, the report is displayed small at the top left corner of the report viewer [see a snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZDyP.png).
After searching a lot in the internet, I think the problem is related to machine resolution which was set by default on my Windows 10 machine to 3840 X 2160. The font size of my machine font was set to 350% which is the maximum which I like . 
I've noticed that when I reduce the machine font size to 100% the report prints fine and is taking the full view of the report viewer but this font size is not readable by humans.
Is there a way or a code which I can write to ignor the machine setting just for this form which holds the report viewer? by the way I've tried to change the
form **AutoScaleMode** property but it didnt' work.

Any kind if help is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue problematically?